# Trying to use "Run once only" controller with "If" controller but sequence of requests is changed under the thread group

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, jmx

description:
I have basic flow to be run concurrency by JMeter.

Scenario:

User asks for Access token and than perform "POST" action (Create some item).
The get access token should be once per ALL Test plan (Across ALL Threads)
For the example I'm using 10 users (Threads) and single iteration (loop_count=1)

Problem:

I've managed to run the get TOKEN only once , but then , the sequence of the requests is changed like something strange , so if I'm running 10 threads - JMeter first try to run 9 request of "Create" and only then run the get Token once and afterwards the last transaction of "Create".

Expected result:

I'm expecting to run first the get Token once and only then run the whole 10 requests of "Create".

Note: Test plan is configured to run in parallel (Consecutive option is UNCHECKED)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear how you're getting the token and passing it across the threads, just in case here is the quote from JMeter documentation:

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

- Once Only Controller makes it's children to run only during first iteration of the thread group
- If Controller makes it's children to run when the condition resolves to `true`

So if you're getting the token by one thread only and storing it into a JMeter Variable - it will be available **to this thread only**

Proposed solution: move your logic for getting the token under the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) with 1 user/1 loop.

Once you get the token - convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function

In your main Thread Group read the token value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Comment: Thanks for your response ,
I do store the token as variable , and as variables can't be forwarded to other thread group , I need to convert it to properties as you suggested , I just thought , there's more convenient way to achieve that goal.
Thanks!